# Flatten an array variable into a single string, while retaining clean formatting

Tags: powershell

I have a variable called `$Properties`, it consists of 3 arrays (All seperated into three lines):

```
NTER 1, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"
NTER 2, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"
NTER 3, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"
```

I wanto flatten the `$Properties` arrays into a single string variable, that looks exactly as above example but with no arrays, so something like this:

```
NTER 1, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"
NTER 2, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"
NTER 3, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"
```

I've tried `$Var = $Properties -join ''` but this takes all three lines and creates a single line:

```
NTER 1, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"NTER 2, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"NTER 3, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"NTER 4, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"LA2 1, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"LA2 2, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"LA2 3, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"LA2 4, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"
```

I've also tried `$Var = $Properties -join "$null"` , still the same issue. Any ideas would be wonderfull. Thanks!

Am on Powershell 7.3 (Preview)

Comment: It's not clear what your expected output is and your `$properties` variables is not syntactically correct. Please edit your question.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: My apologies for any confusion caused, I have not edited the question for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join the strings array with a line break, you can use

- `` "`r`n" ``(CRLF) for Windows style, or
- `` "`n" ``(LF) for Linux style.

Use `` $Var = $Properties -join "`r`n" `` in the code

```
$Properties = @(
  'NTER 1, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"'
  'NTER 2, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"'
  'NTER 3, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"'
)
$Var = $Properties -join "`r`n"
```

It will generate

```
NTER 1, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"
NTER 2, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"
NTER 3, ShortD = "Start > Then Dump", LongD = "Procces is started, then all errors are dumped to a log file"
```